# Not able to create project in Google actions console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-home

I want to integrate home assistant with google home. Therefore i have to create an actions smart home project in the google actions console. But it just wont let me create a project. Tried everything... log out and back in again, different browsers, clear cache... but keep getting an error that something went wrong when creating your project. Please try again later... importing a project throws the same error. Someone had similar issues?

Clear cache. Log out google account. Different browser. Incognito window. Activated my developer account

Comment: Can't reproduce on my end. Have you tried a different gmail account?

Comment: Are you seeing any specific error messages when you try to create a project? If so, please provide the exact wording, as it can offer clues about the issue. Check also the console logs for any additional details

Comment: Havent tried a different account yet... the error message only says.. something went wrong. Pleaae try again later. It lets me give in a name and select smart home. After that when it creates my project it fails with the error that something went wrong

Comment: Same for me. Clicking 'New Project' simply does nothing. I see a 403 in the network tab of the dev tools.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue, and it seems to work after you've set a "country of residence" here: https://console.actions.google.com/subscriptions/overview

Comment: @CPlus: This is more than a link. It’s stating that they need to set their “country of residence”—and then providing the link to where they would set that. They could offer a bit more detail such as explaining how to get to that page without the link, I suppose, but this is more than just a link.